# Ajax always gives positive value. How to correct it?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, smarty

My php code

```
function MailList()
{
    $this->Form['email'] = $_POST["email"];
    $index = $this->mgr->getMailList($_POST["email"]);
}


//sql code

function getMailList($email)
{           
    $mailArray = Array();
    $sql = "select vchEmail as mailName from tbDownloadDetails  where vchEmail='".$email."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->con);
    $isexist=false; 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $isexist=true;
        array_push($mailArray, $row['mailName']);
    }       
    return ($mailArray);
}
```

Ajax Code

```
function getMailList(e)
{       

    $value=e;
    $.ajax({
            url:'http://example.com/report/' + "filedownload.html",
            type:"POST",
            data:{action:'MailList',email:$value},
            dataType:"html",
            success:function (resp) {
                if (resp !== '') {
                    alert("Success");
                } else {
                    alert("Fail");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
         return false;
}
```

This my code. But its not working. When I put a email id it always shows(alert) success, if it is not present in db. that is code gives always positive value. How to correct code.
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
<?php 

function getMailList($email)
{           
    $mailArray = Array();
    $sql = "select vchEmail as mailName from tbDownloadDetails  where vchEmail='".$email."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->con) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            array_push($mailArray, $row['mailName']);
        }   
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }


    return count($mailArray)>0 ? $mailArray : false;
}

?>
```

Ajax code :

```
function getMailList(e)
{       

    $value=e;
    $.ajax({
            url:'http://example.com/report/' + "filedownload.html",
            type:"POST",
            data:{action:'MailList',email:$value},
            dataType:"html",
            success:function (resp) {
                if (resp !== false) {
                    alert("Success");
                } else {
                    alert("Fail");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
         return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your response, you're returning an array. If at all the email doesn't exists, it will return an empty array..

Hence your response will be

> [] instead of ''.

Make changes to your comparison inside the success callback. and check like this.

> resp.length === 0

Answer (score 0):

I assume getMailList() is called when you call your script's action MailList.

You are returning an array. If the email address is not found, you script will return an empty array. Try to check `resp.length === 0` :)

Answer (score 0):

return a string instead `return 'true';` or use `===` to compare.